# Returning MySQL list ordered by "how much of a match" a column is

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I was writing a products search engine for a pet project website and ran into a problem. How do I return products ordered by "how much of a match" they were for the query? Right now I have this, which will only return products where the query matches the beginning.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `Products` WHERE name LIKE '$query%'";
```

Placing a % in front of $query like so

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `Products` WHERE name LIKE '%$query%'"
```

achieves the desired output but it is not ordered correctly. For example, the user searches for "p" and they get a list like: [A-word with p in it], [B-word with p in it], [P-word]. I would like the P-word to show up first, and the A & B words to show up after it. Is this possible with only MySQL? I've looked into [ORDER BY](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_orderby.asp) but that orders by columns AFAIK.

Comment: `ORDER BY LOCATE('$query', name)` is about the best you can do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with `order by`:

```
SELECT *
FROM `Products`
WHERE name LIKE '%$query%'"
ORDER BY (name like '$query%') desc,
         name;
```

The first clause will put the names that start with `$query` first.